# What is the ideal way to create view-instance-specific bindings in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js

I have a view that is instantiated in an {{#each}} block, so there are multiple instances. Each view needs to have a bound property to an object that is specific to that view instance. So the usual way of declaring a binding:

```
App.hash = Ember.Object.create({
   item1: "one",
   item2: "two"
});
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
   itemBinding: "App.hash.itemN"
});
```

won't work because When I define what the binding maps to (`App.hash.itemN`) I don't know yet whether it should be item1 or item2 (represented in the above code by itemN).

I have found a way around this, that seems a bit kludgey, and am curious if there's a proper way. Here is my solution:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
   didInsertElement: function() {
      this.set('stub', Ember.Object.create({
        itemBinding: "App.hash."+this.get('content')}))
   }
})
```

Then in my template I can do the following:

```
{{#each App.itemController}}
   {{#view App.MyView contentBinding="this"}}
      {{stub.item}}
   {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

Is there a better way to do this? My complaints are that I feel like I'm creating an unnecessary object. Also, if I want other properties of my view to depend on this instance-specific object, I can say `.property(stub.item)` which happens to work, despite that when it's declared, stub.item doesn't exist yet.

I thought there might be some way involving manually creating a binding, but I couldn't figure that out.

Thanks!

Update:

I've confirmed that Christopher Swasey's solution works. I've fleshed it out in this Gist:

https://gist.github.com/2606979

This was very helpful, as I learned more about observes and callbacks. Although in the end, I'm not sure how much simpler this solution is. Nonetheless, it works at least as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make stub a computed property:

```
hashBinding: 'App.hash',
stub: function() {
    return this.get('hash').get(this.get('content'))
}.property('hash', 'content').cacheable()
```

Updated:

```
contentWillChange: function() {
    this.removeObserver('hash.' + this.get('content'), this, 'stubDidChange');
}.observesBefore('content'),

contentDidChange: function() {
    this.addObserver('hash.' + this.get('content'), this, 'stubDidChange');
    this.stubDidChange();
}.observes('content'),

stubDidChange: function() {
    this.notifyPropertyChange('stub');
},

stub: function() {
    return this.get('hash').get(this.get('content'))
}.property().cacheable()
```

Comment: The problem is the computed property would need to be called when App.hash.item1 changes. But the computed property as defined above only watches App.hash itself. And when I extend the view, I don't know which item in App.hash to bind to. It's only once I instantiate the view that the info I need is bound to "this".

Comment: I've updated to show how to set up the observers in this case

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I've confirmed your solution works and updated my question accordingly.