# Emberjs - Binding parameters dynamically to a view

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I am trying to create editable views for a select group of parameters in my models.

[The jsfiddle is worth a thousand words!](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVFH2/5/)

As you can see, it is linking the content to the actual string - not the path, as in the working (but not dynamic) second ParameterView.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406771/what-is-the-ideal-way-to-create-view-instance-specific-bindings-in-emberjs), but it is an extremely clunky solution, especially when I have about 20 or so parameters per model, with four different models.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for sharing your brain power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understand well, does it work for you ? http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/ZVFH2/9/

***Update***

I think I found a way to do this, by defining binding at runtime, using the `bind()` function.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/ZVFH2/34/

Comment: Sexy! It works - but why doesn't the second ParameterView update when the first one is changed? Aren't they bound to the same parameter?

Comment: nop, in the first view, "this" represent an item of the viewableParams property (not the content), and the secondView, it's the "content.name".

Comment: hmm... that's because the #each changes the scope? I am trying to get them both to bind to App.itemController.content.name - so the second vew is achieving that, but the first view is creating a new property in viewableParams?

Comment: Yes, so you want the changes from one view to be reflected to the other ?

Comment: Yes - I would like the first view to bind to App.itemController.content.name. I will not be using the second view - that was just there as an example of what I was trying to achieve with the #each.